# Should (confirmed) future appointments be mentioned in an academic CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

Background: CS Undergraduate India.

I have a confirmation about an internship for Jan - July 2022 but will send out applications of PhD CS USA Programs on Nov 2021.

**Question:**
Should I add that on my CV?

Reasons why I want to do it:

1. I have interned at the place before under some other prof on a similar topic but won't be using his LOR as I wasn't able to find anything strikingly new.
2. The institute is extremely prestigious. One of the best in the country.
3. I will be mentioning that in my SOP because it aligns with my work I am conducting for my senior thesis.

**Note:** I already have previous research experience and papers so I am not doing it to really "pad" my CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your situation to publications:

it is [acceptable](https://brocku.ca/career/students/workshops/CV_Workshop/story_content/external_files/CV%20Writing%20-%20How%20to%20Cite%20Publications%20in%20APA.pdf) to add paper that is not yet out, but has been accepted by the journal. In this case we write "(in print)" instead of "published on June 30, 2021"

If you have signed contract, it is OK to write "accepted internship at ___". Whether it's going to help you or not is a different story.

As we don't add papers as "submitted to Nature", don't add jobs you applied to, but haven't finalized contract.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was exactly what I was looking for (especially the contract aspect of things)!